# align a table in different layouts?

Tags: android, alignment, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I´m using 2 tables side by side in a LinearLayout and they´re both filling 50% of the screens width. Below that LinearLayout, there is a RelativeLayout with another table in it.

Something like this:

```
<LinearLayout>
      <TableLayout>
           <TableRow>
            ...
           </TableRow>
      </TableLayout>

      <TableLayout>
           <TableRow>
            ...
           </TableRow>
      </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout>

      ... some views ...

      <TableLayout>
           <TableRow>
            ...
           </TableRow>
      </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now I want the table in the RelativeLayout to have same width as the first table in the LinearLayout. I thought that I could do it with `android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Linearlayout_table1"`, but that´s not working.

So, is there a way to do this?

Comment: For that property to work the referenced layouts should be contained inside the RelativeLayout.

Comment: and wht about the remaining space that will be left after painting the TableView in RelativeLayout..r u gonna add some other view der?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a LinearLayout in place of the RelativeLayout and include an empty  element to provide the correct weighting. Note: Set the layout_height to whatever you want.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
```